# If a process is dominated by an integrable variable, then this process is of class $\mathcal D$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a filtration of $\mathcal F$
- $\mathcal D$ be the set of product measurable processes $X$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathcal F,\operatorname P)$ such that $(X_\tau:\tau\text{ is a finite stopping time on }(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathcal F,\operatorname P))$ is uniformly integrable

> How can we show that if $X$ is a product measurable process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathcal F,\operatorname P)$ with $$|X|\le|Y|\;\;\;\text{almost surely}\tag1$$ for some $Y\in L^1(\operatorname P)$, then $X\in\mathcal D$?

I've read this claim in *Stochastic Integration Theorey* by Péter Medvegyev, Corollary 1.145. However, I don't see why the claim is true.

If $Y$ would belong to $L^p(\operatorname P)$ for some $p>1$, then it would be clear to me, since $(1)$ yields the $L^p$-boundedness of $(X_\tau:\tau\text{ is a finite stopping time on }(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathcal F,\operatorname P))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have **any** collection $\mathcal A$ of random variables that is dominated by an integrable random variable $Y$, then $\mathcal A$ is uniformly integrable. This is because for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $$ P(A) < \delta \implies E[|Y|1_A]<\epsilon \implies \sup_{X \in \mathcal A} E[|X|1_A]< \epsilon$$

Now note that if $|X(t, \omega)| \leq |Y(\omega)|$, then for any a.s. finite stopping time $\tau$ we also have that $|X(\tau(\omega),\omega)| \leq |Y(\omega)|$; hence the collection $\mathcal A:=\{X_{\tau}:\tau$ a finite stopping time$\}$ is dominated by $Y$.

Comment: Could you explain why the first implication holds?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Sure, because a single intgrable random variable is always uniformly integrable. Another way to see this is that the measure $dQ= |X|dP$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $P$. If you want a direct proof, then suppose the implication does not hold. Then $\forall k\in \Bbb N$ there exists some $E_k$ such that $P(E)< 2^{-k}$ and yet $E[Y1_A]>\epsilon$. Then we take $E:= \bigcap_n \bigcup_{k \geq n} E_k$. Then $P(E)=0$ but $E[Y1_E] \geq \epsilon$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry, meant $dQ=Y dP$.